# How to send a GET request using C++?

Tags: c++, http, get, request, winsock2

I have an API url:

https://ru.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/NikolayDark16?api_key=RGAPI-b2971736-9178-4559-a0d9-7d166093865c

When I try to make a `GET` request to it, the response is `302 Moved Temporarily`.

My request is:

```
std::string write_buf = "GET /lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/NikolayDark16?api_key=RGAPI-b2971736-9178-4559-a0d9-7d166093865c HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: www.riotgames.com\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "\r\n";
```

If I use `Host www.ru.api.riotgames.com` instead, the response is `400 bad request`.

Comment: This isn't a complete enough example to provide any advice. This is just a bunch of strings smashed into a question. Can you give something more complete that shows how these are used?

Comment: I need parse https://ru.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/NikolayDark16?api_key=RGAPI-b2971736-9178-4559-a0d9-7d166093865c, help me create right request

Comment: That's something you'll have to tackle yourself. It's too broad in scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I create request as in the photo https://ibb.co/dTsRYA, but error 400 bad request

Comment: Each API behaves differently, and you'll need to study the documentation to find out what you need to do and/or contact support or a forum for this specific service.

Comment: In my opinion openssl lib has bad documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 302 response is a redirect to another URL. Simply resend the same request to the URL specified in the response's `Location` header.

As for the 400 response, the correct hostname to specify in the request's `Host` header is `ru.api.riotgames.com` (no `www.` in front). And don't forget the `:` after `Host`.

```
std::string write_buf = "GET /lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/NikolayDark16?api_key=RGAPI-b2971736-9178-4559-a0d9-7d166093865c HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: ru.api.riotgames.com\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "\r\n";
```

Comment: My mistake was that I recognized the ip for riotgames.com and not ru.api.riotgames.com, it turned out that they have different ip addresses

Comment: if I use cite with domain name .ua or .gg BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "www.olx.ua:443") gives an error message